# figure won't show in while loop

Tags: python, plot, while-loop

as it will take a long time to deal with some data, I need to draw lines in a while loop after the data is okay. But figure can not show in the while loop, now I will paste a simplified code which can also mirror the same question. thank u for ur patience.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,2*pi,20)
y=np.sin(x)
z=np.cos(x)
while 1:
    nPlt = input('input nPlt:')
    if nPlt == 1:
        plt.plot(x,y)
    elif nPlt == 2:
        plt.plot(x,z)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you change your code to this

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x=np.linspace(0,2*pi,20)
    y=np.sin(x)
    z=np.cos(x)
    while 1:
        nPlt = eval(input('input nPlt:')) #Note eval was added
            if nPlt == 1:
                plt.plot(x,y)
            elif nPlt == 2:
                plt.plot(x,z)
            else:
                break
    plt.show() #Note I added this line
```

This is for python 3. I believe for python 2 instead of the eval you can use raw_input.

Comment: It's really weird that the codes you modified can run well in IDEL(2.7.6), but not the same in spyder(Python 2.7). the software I use to compile the code is python(x,y) which doesn't respond when plot in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)
y=np.sin(x)
z=np.cos(x)
while 1:
    nPlt = input('input nPlt:')
    if nPlt == 1:
        plt.plot(x,y)
    elif nPlt == 2:
        plt.plot(x,z)
    else:
        break
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Two things, pi should be np.pi; added plt.draw() to draw the plot and plt.pause(0.1) (or some other time) to allow the figure some time to be shown.

Comment: thank u for your patience, ur answer is very helpful and throw light upon certain process. There's lots of stuff for me to learn.